# Finding value (Trigo Series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Find the value of $$\cos ^2\theta+\cos^2 (\theta+1^{\circ})+\cos^2(\theta+2^{\circ})+......+\cos^2(\theta+179^{\circ})$$

Can anyone teach me where to start with? I've no idea.

Comment: Use $\cos (90+\theta)= -\sin \theta $ , you'd find enough pairs. :D

Answer (score 1):

I am not claiming that this is the best approach, but you could try and use double angle formula
$$cos(2\theta)=2cos^2(\theta)-1$$
so this should simplify your equations into
$$\frac{cos(2\theta)+1}{2}+\frac{cos(2(\theta+1^{\circ}))+1}{2}+\ldots$$
Now, use Euler's formula (I don't know what people call this)
$$e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$$
and you should spot something there.